# malloc() Crashing everytime || windbg breaks in with nt!DbgLoadImageSymbols

Tags: c, windows, malloc, windbg

```
LPTSTR name = NULL;
DWORD nameLength = 0;

namelength = host->nameLength; // returns 10
name =  (LPTSTR) malloc( sizeof(nameLength * sizeof(TCHAR))); //crashes here
```

I don't understand the reason for its crashing at this point. Could somebody explain why?

Update =*(deleted the next line after the crashing line, had copied it by mistake. was just a commented out line in the code)

UPDATE:
Sorry guys, I had tried all the ways you have described before asking the question. Doesn't work.

I think its some other issue. heres a windows service, calling up the function above (from a dll) when the computer starts, so was doing a remote debugging the dll using windbg ( I break-in using a hard-coded debugbreak, just before the function gets called).

when I am over the malloc step and give a "next step" instruction (F10), it doesn't go to the next step, instead says the client is running, but then suddenly breaks in at nt!DbgLoadImageSymbols with "leave" instruction. Giving a go(F5) after this keeps the machine in a hanged state.

Comment: Can't really tell without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: did you try `malloc(nameLength * sizeof(TCHAR))`?

Comment: You've got too many sizeof's in there. Should be `malloc( nameLength * sizeof(TCHAR) )`

Comment: What would you expect the size of a product to be?

Comment: According to this definition http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof the argument of the `sizeof` operator must be a type. I am a bit surprised that this actually compiles.

Comment: Also, it makes no sense to immediately assign something else to `name`, discarding the pointer you just for from malloc.

Comment: Ah yes, now I see. nameLength * sizeof(TCHAR) is an integer of some sort, so that other sizeof is returning sizeof(int). I don't think  that is what you want.

Comment: Codor I don't believe that is true, at least not in C.

Comment: @TheBigH it's most likely an `unsigned long` since `DWORD` is a typedef for `unsigned long` and `sizeof` itself returns a `size_t`, which is also a typedef of `unsigned long` in Windows.

Comment: Can you add TCHAR in the description?

Comment: @mch- Sure, probably. The point is, it's some kind of integer. Doesn't particularly matter which kind.

Comment: @Codor That page clearly has the `sizeof expression` syntax too.

Comment: It should probably be `malloc( (nameLength+1) * sizeof(TCHAR) )` to allow room for the terminator.

Comment: Adding to @Jonathon Reinhart, how are you going to `free(name)` when you have thrown away the pointer from `malloc()`?

Comment: Please create a complete compilable example, describe your crash and how you identified the `malloc` line as the cause. A call to `malloc` should never cause a crash (`<stdlib.h>` included?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you crash inside of `malloc`, then it means that you have previously corrupted the heap (or more accurately, the double-linked lists that organize the heap).

Considering that you have a glaring bug here:

```
name =  (LPTSTR) malloc( sizeof(nameLength * sizeof(TCHAR)));
```

You should review all of your malloc calls and ensure that you are allocating enough memory. What you have likely done is allocate too small of a buffer, written too much data into the returned pointer corrupting the heap, and then crashed in a later call to malloc.

Since you are on Windows, you can also utilize [page-heap verification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549557.aspx) (via the gflags tool). This will help you catch buffer overwrites when they happen.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info for an answer, but too much for a comment, sorry. I made a simple `main()` based as closely on your clues as I can see, with any previously commented errors uncorrected, but extra lines FYI how much memory is allocated. The program compiles and runs without complaint. So your problem has not been properly expressed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(){
    LPTSTR name = NULL;
    DWORD nameLength = 10;
    name =  (LPTSTR) malloc( sizeof(nameLength * sizeof(TCHAR)));
    if (name) {
        printf ("Memory for %d bytes allocated\n", sizeof(nameLength * sizeof(TCHAR)));
        free (name);
    } else {
        printf ("No memory for %d bytes\n", sizeof(nameLength * sizeof(TCHAR)));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Memory for 4 bytes allocated
```

What *is* clear, is that it's unlikely to be enough memory for whatever you have said is 10.

Comment: It goes exactly the way you have it there. I don't get it! why is it crashing just for me. exactly at the point when trying to allocate the memory. What are the different number of reasons, for a malloc to crash?

Its a function in a dll, called up from a windows service.

Comment: *"Its a function in a dll, called up from a windows service.*" So my simple `main()` isn't *exactly* what you have done. I'm out of here ;-)